# How to choose vinyl laminate

Tags: vinyl-flooring

The flooring for a rental is to be replaced.  Durability can be measured:

https://www.carpetcaptain.com/laminate-floor-guide/ac-rating/

What are the other features should be considered when selecting and why?

Comment: I reversed the downvote because there was no reason provided for it. I believe there is a walking test that some refer to I did not check the link. Ease of installing (will it crack stretch , premier glue only etc).

Comment: Flood resistance, total sealing and ease of repair and tear out come to mind.  If water damage ruins a laminated wood floorboard in the middle of a room in the middle of a floor with continuous flooring, how will you repair it?  If you install rubber tile in a bathroom, does it lock together well enough that pooled water will not seep through?  How easy is the material to cut?